# How can I efficiently buffer a network stream to a file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

In our web application, we are trying to allow users download large files (upwards of tens of gigabytes) for a file storage application. Currently we have a client side download method using the (now discontinued) LocalFileSystem (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem) feature.

Our reason for moving from our previous method of server-side downloads to a javascript-based solution was for error handling and progress reporting. The files actually stored in chunks, and we need to stream them from the server to the client upon download. However, due to compression and several other factors, we cannot determine the content length before initializing the download, so any attempt to set a content-length header would be futile.

Without using LocalFileSystem, browsers like FireFox are forced to load the entire file in a javascript object in ram out of local storage to prompt the user to save the file.

My question is this: Is there any way to save these files via javascript (without loading the entire thing in ram)? or are we forced to move back to our server side download?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a position you can manage the browser profile? You can break the browser sandbox and escalate the current profile's privileges if you have that type of control over your application. Is this over the web for just any user or is this something launched from local disk that just uses the browser?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a comment and not an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately this is over the web and we have no way of managing the profile. In addition, we need to support a wide range of browsers, from IE8 FF and Chrome. Currently, we fall back to server side downloads for these browsers, but the UX is terrible.

Comment: Anything you do is going to be brittle and browser-specific. The browser-sandbox was designed to prevent the page from saving anything without explicit user interaction. Probably fool around with how it caches css or something but all very kludgy and I won't want to go that direction.

Comment: @techie.brandon I don't mind if we need to get user permission to save the file. If they need to click our download button, then need to give permission to save, that would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: For each segment? How would to combine at the end?

Comment: IMO it would be better to have a backend process combine these in a temp location with a time-to-live timer that kills them after a expiration period. Give the UI final file reference, obviously this has its own issues.

Comment: @techie.brandon The preferable method would be to request permission once for the file. The first dialog to give permission to download, then the script just appends all data it receives, then prompts the user to save in a permanent location. I realize that that may not specifically possible, which is why I am open to alternate solutions.

Comment: Sorry, not much help to you without having hta or advanced chrome/firefox profiles. :(